# Error handling over websockets a design dessision

Tags: javascript, rest, clojure, architecture, websocket

Im currently building a webapp that has two clear use cases.

1. Traditional client request data from server.
2. Client request a stream from the server after wich the server starts pushing data to the client.

Currently im implementing both 1 and 2 using json message passing over a websocket. However this has proven hard since I need to handcode lots of error handling since the client is not waiting for the response. It just sends the message hoping it will get a reply sometime.
Im using Js and react on the frontend and Clojure on the backend.

I have two questions regarding this.

1. Given the current design, what alternatives are there for error handling over a websocket?
2. Would it be smarter to split the two UC using rest for UC1 and websockets for UC2 then i could use something like `fetch` on the frontend for rest calls.

Update.
The current problem is not knowing how to build an async send function over websockets can match send messages and response messages.

Comment: It is not trivial to build request/response in the webSocket messaging architecture.  It is not naturally request/response.  You will probably have to do it with some sort of message ID in each message and response so when you send a message you know which response belongs to that message from the ID you put in each.

Comment: So you would say using rest and websockets side by side is easier?

Comment: Well, http is natural request/response and it's easy to use for that.  But, you can't do request/response with HTTP from server to client if that's what you're trying to do.  If your requests are from client to server, then yes HTTP and REST is just easier for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a scheme for doing request/response over socket.io.  You could do this over plain webSocket, but you'd have to build a little more of the infrastructure yourself.  This same library can be used in client and server:

```
function initRequestResponseSocket(socket, requestHandler) {
    var cntr = 0;
    var openResponses = {};

    // send a request
    socket.sendRequestResponse = function(data, fn) {
        // put this data in a wrapper object that contains the request id
        // save the callback function for this id
        var id = cntr++;
        openResponses[id] = fn;
        socket.emit('requestMsg', {id: id, data: data});
    }

    // process a response message that comes back from a request
    socket.on('responseMsg', function(wrapper) {
        var id = wrapper.id, fn;
        if (typeof id === "number" && typeof openResponses[id] === "function") {
            fn = openResponses[id];
            delete openResponses[id];
            fn(wrapper.data);
        }
    });

    // process a requestMsg
    socket.on('requestMsg', function(wrapper) {
        if (requestHandler && wrapper.id) {
            requestHandler(wrapper.data, function(responseToSend) {
                socket.emit('responseMsg', {id: wrapper.id, data; responseToSend});
            });
        }
    });
}
```

This works by wrapping every message sent in a wrapper object that contains a unique id value.  Then, when the other end sends it's response, it includes that same id value.  That id value can then be matched up with a particular callback response handler for that specific message.  It works both ways from client to server or server to client.

You use this by calling `initRequestResponseSocket(socket, requestHandler)` once on a socket.io socket connection on each end.  If you wish to receive requests, then you pass a requestHandler function which gets called each time there is a request.  If you are only sending requests and receiving responses, then you don't have to pass in a requestHandler on that end of the connection.

To send a message and wait for a response, you do this:

```
socket.sendRequestResponse(data, function(err, response) {
    if (!err) {
        // response is here
    }
});
```

If you're receiving requests and sending back responses, then you do this:

```
initRequestResponseSocket(socket, function(data, respondCallback) {
   // process the data here

   // send response
   respondCallback(null, yourResponseData);
});
```

As for error handling, you can monitor for a loss of connection and you could build a timeout into this code so that if a response doesn't arrive in a certain amount of time, then you'd get an error back.

Here's an expanded version of the above code that implements a timeout for a response that does not come within some time period:

```
function initRequestResponseSocket(socket, requestHandler, timeout) {
    var cntr = 0;
    var openResponses = {};

    // send a request
    socket.sendRequestResponse = function(data, fn) {
        // put this data in a wrapper object that contains the request id
        // save the callback function for this id
        var id = cntr++;
        openResponses[id] = {fn: fn};
        socket.emit('requestMsg', {id: id, data: data});
        if (timeout) {
            openResponses[id].timer = setTimeout(function() {
                delete openResponses[id];
                if (fn) {
                    fn("timeout");
                }
            }, timeout);
        }
    }

    // process a response message that comes back from a request
    socket.on('responseMsg', function(wrapper) {
        var id = wrapper.id, requestInfo;
        if (typeof id === "number" && typeof openResponse[id] === "object") {
            requestInfo = openResponses[id];
            delete openResponses[id];
            if (requestInfo) {
                if (requestInfo.timer) {
                    clearTimeout(requestInfo.timer);
                }
                if (requestInfo.fn) {
                    requestInfo.fn(null, wrapper.data);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    // process a requestMsg
    socket.on('requestMsg', function(wrapper) {
        if (requestHandler && wrapper.id) {
            requestHandler(wrapper.data, function(responseToSend) {
                socket.emit('responseMsg', {id: wrapper.id, data; responseToSend});
            });

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of interesting things in your question and your design, I prefer to ignore the implementation details and look at the high level architecture.

You state that you are looking to a client that requests data and a server that responds with some stream of data. Two things to note here:

1. HTTP 1.1 has options to send streaming responses (*Chunked transfer encoding*). If your use-case is only the sending of streaming responses, this might be a better fit for you. This does not hold when you e.g. want to push messages to the client that are not responding to some sort of request (sometimes referred to as *Server side events*).
2. Websockets, contrary to HTTP, do not natively implement some sort of request-response cycle. You can use the protocol as such by implementing your own mechanism, something that e.g. the subprotocol [WAMP](http://wamp-proto.org) is doing.

As you have found out, implementing your own mechanism comes with it's pitfalls, that is where HTTP has the clear advantage. Given the requirements stated in your question I would opt for the HTTP streaming method instead of implementing your own request/response mechanism.

Comment: The server will push messages to clients without a request. That is why im considering using rest ans ws or implement send response logic and go with only ws.